# Android Studio Canary - can't find Code Style options

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm using:

Android Studio 3.5 Canary 13

Build #AI-191.6183.87.35.5487692, built on April 19, 2019

JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.4

And I can't find "Code Style" options - from what I remember (and on stable build) they were in Editor-> Code Style, but in Canary build this option is gone. Were they moved somewhere else?

[image]

Comment: tried using "search" field atop?

Comment: Yes and it is not there (after inputing "code style" in search).

Comment: I just checked and on stable build it is just under "Color Scheme" so wonder where it was moved on a Canary build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved ("Code Style" option is back in same place in Android Studio Preferences) in 3.5 Beta 1. Seems like AS issue.